# Notation doubt: Is $\nabla f(x(u,v), y(u,v))$ the same as $\nabla f(u, v)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> Is $\nabla f(x(u,v), y(u,v))$ the same as $\nabla f(u, v)$?

Background: Was solving [this assignment](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/2.-partial-derivatives/part-a-functions-of-two-variables-tangent-approximation-and-optimization/problem-set-4/MIT18_02SC_SupProb2.pdf), problem E-7.

Kinda confused here, would appreciate help.

Comment: Yes, the idea is to verify that changing coordinates from $(x,y)$ to $(u,v)$ can be accomplished through a usual tool.

Comment: In principle, those are not the same. $f(x(u,v),y(u,v))$ is a different function of $(u,v)$ and you should call it something else, like $g(u,v)$. $g$ is the composition of $f$ with your change of variables $(u,v)\to(x,y)$. The exercise is on the chain rule for functions of two variables, and you end up with things like $g_u=f_x\cdot x_u+f_y\cdot y_u$ and similar for the derivative with respect to $v$.

Comment: The distinction is very clear for mathematicians. However, in Physics or engineering books sometimes they keep the same name for the function. This is because physicists and engineers look at these as quantities, not as functions in the mathematical sense of the term. So they say $f(u,v)$, meaning that we look at the same quantity as before, but as a function of $(u,v)$ instead of $(x,y)$.